# Dynamic Merging of Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am writing a program in python which asks the user to select 5 symbols. After the user selects five symbols the program will provide various outputs.

The way the program currently works it creates five uniquely named pandas dataframes and then joins them into one frame as below.

```
data1 = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
data2 = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
data3 = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
data4 = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
data5 = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
```

I want to improve the program so the user could select any number of stocks and the program would build one pandas dataframe. I am thinking it would be similar to an append query in a SQL database. For the purposes of this question I am keeping the symbol list static in size.

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2018, 5, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 5, 31)

symbol_list = ['IVV', 'EWH', 'INDY', 'EWG', 'ENZL']
for symbols in Symbol_List:
    symbol = symbols
    data = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'iex', start, end)
```

add something here to append the new data into a master dataframe.

The append would need to rewrite the column names to include the symbols, add the columns for the new data, and ensure the data index lines up.

I was thinking something like:

```
data.rename(columns={'high': 'high' + symbol, 'low': 'low' + symbol}, inplace=True)
pd.merge(masterdata, data, on='index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) with list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join together:

```
data = pd.concat([pdr.DataReader(s, 'iex', start, end).add_suffix(s) for s in symbol_list], axis=1)
```

Comment: The ad_prefix is throwing an attribute error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ad_prefix'.

Comment: I tried this:
data = pandas.concat([pdr.DataReader(s, 'iex', start, end)
                      rename(columns={'high': 'high' + s, 'low': 'low' + s}, inplace=True)
                      for s in Indexlist], axis=1)

which gave a syntax error

Comment: Try remove inplace= True